# como parsear un documento XML para imprimirlo en consola

Tags: python, xml

Buenas tardes, necesito ayuda para parsear un documento .XML en Python, solo necesito saber la mejor forma de printearlo en la consola (bash o cmd). la cuestion es que ya he logrado parsear el documento, mas en el mismo hay elementos que se repiten ejemplo `<p>`. Como hago para imprimir todos los elementos asi como sus childs cuando estos se repiten. en otras palabras quiero imprimir `<p>` y sus childs (`tag` y `texto`) y como este se repite tambien imprimirlo. si me explique?.... De antemano las gracias a los que puedan colaborar. Saludos!

documento XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resulset>
  <a>
    <r_l>text 1</r_l>
    <v>1.0</v>
    <o_g>
      <t>text 2</t>
      <o>text 3</o>
      <d>text 4</d>
    </o_g>
    <ps>
      <p>
        <t>text 5</t>
        <i_n>text 6</i_n>
        <ln>text 7</ln>
        <fn>text 8</fn>
        <p_t></p_t>
        <db></db>
        <fi>text 9</fi>
        <ff></ff>
      </p>
      <p>
        <t>text 10</t>
        <i_n>text 11</i_n>
        <ln>text 12</ln>
        <fn>text 13</fn>
        <p_t>text 14</p_t>
        <db></db>
        <fi>text 15</fi>
        <ff></ff>
      </p>
    </ps>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y añadir tu programa en Python que has escrito ya para que podamos ver que API has utilizado y mejorarlo en lugar de escribir todo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no quieres hacer uso de librerías externas, puedes utilizar el código descrito en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4590052/2137913) de otro hilo similar en inglés. Lo que esa respuesta propone es definir una función *indent* (aproximadamente traducido como 'tabular') con la lógica necesaria para añadir tantos espacios y saltos de línea como sea necesario, para mostrar cada elemento del árbol XML en su posición correcta según el nivel de profundidad del elemento. Te incluyo el código aquí por comodidad.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree                                                                                  

def indent(elem, level=0):                                                                                         
    i = "\n" + level*"  "                                                                                          
    j = "\n" + (level-1)*"  "                                                                                      
    if len(elem):                                                                                                  
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():                                                                 
            elem.text = i + "  "                                                                                   
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():                                                                 
            elem.tail = i                                                                                          
        for subelem in elem:                                                                                       
            indent(subelem, level+1)                                                                               
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():                                                                 
            elem.tail = j                                                                                          
    else:                                                                                                          
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):                                                     
            elem.tail = j                                                                                          
    return elem                                                                                                    

root = ElementTree.parse('mi_archivo.xml').getroot()                                                       
indent(root)                                                                                                       
ElementTree.dump(root)
```

Si prefieres usar una librería externa, puedes usar [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Para instalarlo, según tu versión de Python, ejecuta el comando:

```
# Python 2
pip install beautifulsoup4
# Python 3
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Por último, para usarlo en tu código fuente:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bs = BeautifulSoup(open('mi_archivo.xml'), 'xml')
print bs.prettify()
```